# Use Alibaba cloud's OSS Image Processing to create thumbnail images

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I am using Alibaba-cloud. Using its Object Storage Service Image processing, I need to generate square thumbnails of images. But those thumbnails must be resized in a way that it fits the square perfectly. **They shouldn't lose its aspect ratio** and the extra portions must get cropped. The thumbnails should look just like the thumbnail images that are shown in any gallery app on phones. How should I achieve this?

Comment: @Gorgamite that's sharing knowledge. SO provides a way to answer your own question right on the ask question screen. I don't care about points. I just did that.

Answer (score 1):

OSS provides a way to scale an image up or down using Resize operation. You can create a smaller cropped version of your images using the fixed width and height method. This method handles automatic cropping, hence your aspect ratio will persist. To do this, there are a few parameters that you must know:

- m - scaling mode (fixed/fill/pad/mfit/lfit)
- w - width
- h - height

To create your thumbnails,

you must set scaling mode to fill. Fill mode retains a cropped and a centered minimum image extending out of the rectangle of the specified width and height. **m_fill**

And lastly, you must set the w and h parameters; for your use case, it will help them to be equal. **h_100**, **w_100**

So this is what your URL will end with: **x-oss-process=image/resize,m_fill,h_100,w_100**

So you can resize [any image](http://image-demo.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/example.jpg) to an [image like this](http://image-demo.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/example.jpg?x-oss-process=image/resize,m_fill,h_100,w_100).

Answer (score 1):

Alibaba Cloud OSS Image Processing (IMG) is an image processing service provides API to process the images effectively.

You can simply request a thumbnail of the images by creating a style.

Style:

> Image Service allows you to save image processing operations and parameters as an alias, that is, a style. With styles, a series of operations can be achieved through a very short URL.

Channel:

> A channel is a namespace of image processing, and the management entity for billing, permission control, logging, and other advanced functions.

- A Channel can have multiple styles. Currently, a Channel is allowed to have up to 50 styles.
- A style can be applied to change all Objects in a Channel.

  > For example, if style abc is in  Channel A and the style content is 100w.jpg (scaled to 100 in width and saved as a .jpg file),  style abc can be applied to all the Objects in Channel A to scale them to 100 in width and saved them as .jpg files.
- A style is only effective within a Channel, that is, the Objects in Channel A cannot use any style in Channel B.

The URL format for image processing by style is as follows:

> http://userdomain/object?x-oss-process=style/name